# I want to change the visibility of a div to visible by default it is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

This is my code in which I have set the div visibility by default hidden

```
<div id="addComments" align="center" style="width:300px; height:300px; visibility:hidden">
    <button>Submit</button>
    <button>Cancel</button>
</div>
```

but when I click on this link I want to change the visibility of a div to visible.

```
<a href="javascript:addMethod()">+ Create a new comment</a>
```

the method behind this link is as follows:

```
function addMethod() {
    try {

        var obj = document.getElementById('addComments');
        obj.visibility = "visible";
        var mashupId = _settings.ratedObjectId;
        var tenantId = _settings.tenantId;
        var comments = null;
        var user = { "Id": 2007, "FirstName": "Ufone", "LastName": "", "EmailAddress": "ahmed.ali@vidizmo.com509" };
        var ratingInfo = {
            "Id": 0,
            "TenantId": tenantId,
            "UserId": user.Id,
            "FirstName": user.FirstName,
            "LastName": user.LastName,
            "Rating": 0,
            "EmailAddress": user.EmailAddress,
            "Comments": comments,
            "RatedObjectTypeInfo": { "Id": 2 },
            "RatingTypeInfo": { "Id": 1 },
            "MashupRatingInfo": { "MashupMetaInfoId": mashupId },
            "RatedObjectId": mashupId,
            "TotalCount": 0
        };

        var url = "http://services.farooq.tv/RatingInfoManagementService/RatingInfoManagementService.svc/ajax/AddRating";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: JSON.stringify(ratingInfo),
            contentType: "application/json",
            timeout: 5000,
            success: function (d) {
                console.log(d);
                if (d == true) {

                    alert("Thank you");
                }
                else {

                    alert("Rewrite");
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log(xhr);
            }



        });

    }
    catch (err) {

        alert(err);}

}
```

Please help; I'm new to programming.

Comment: You should try **obj.style.visibility** and not **obj.visibility** in your code.

Comment: can u show a snippet of your HTML code as well ?! and r u using some Javascript frameworks like jQuery ?!

Comment: Its not just an end i want more favour that is I to add text in this div can any one tell me that how to add text property and save it in a comment variable i.e. in here  var comments = null; and post it to the service???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you use one of the Javascript frameworks available .. for example jQuery makes life much easier .. you can use the selectos provided there to simply pick whatever element you want .. afterwards you can handle CSS changes easily

for example:

```
$(selector).css("attribue","value");
or $(selector).show(); //or hide()
```

Comment: how to add a text in a div and save it in a  var comments = null;

Comment: use api.jquery.com :)  method "append"

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with css, use "style.visibility" (i.e. obj.style.visibility = "visible")

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
var obj = document.getElementById('addComments');
obj.visibility = "visible";
```

To

```
$('#addComments').show()
```